# Windows batch: data from file disappears after delayed expansion

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I'm using a windows command prompt script to read values from different .txt files. First it works, but then later the array seems to be empty.

analyze.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ID=P8
set comptype=Link
set pattern=(700 710 720 730 740 750 760 770 780 790 ) 

set n=0
for %%i in %pattern% do (
set j=0
for /f "tokens=1-5" %%a in (.\results\%%i.txt) do (
  if %%a==%comptype% if %%b==Results (set t=%%d)
  if %%a==%ID% (
  set data[%n%][%j%]=%%b
  echo !data[%n%][%j%]!                      <-- This is working
  set /a j=!j!+1 )
)
set /a n=!n!+1
)

for /l %%o in (0, 1, %n%) do (
for /l %%k in (0, 1, %j%) do (
echo %data[%%o][%%k]%                        <-- This is not working
))
```

The second echo just prints: "ECHO is off.", which leads me to believe that the variable is empty at that point.
Could it have something to do with the delayed expansion of 'data'? 
Using ! instead of % for the second echo does not change anything.
EndLocal before or after the last two for-loops also does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
set "data[!n!][!j!]=%%b"
...
...
echo !data[%%o][%%k]!
```

Comment: It does not help, also prints "ECHO is off."

Comment: It works, thank you!
I also had to decrease n and j by 1, but that's a different story.

Comment: The CALL isn't needed here, `echo !data[%%o][%%k]!` should work too

Comment: Yes, I forgot the delayed expansion is global.

Comment: @jeb is rite, it seems the set line was the problem here

Comment: Yes, inside a for loop the %variables% can't change their value, never ever. You must always use !variables!.